# How to destroy a b2Body in Box2D (cocos2d)? After checking the traveld distance

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone, projectile

I have bullets in box2d/cocos2d-for-iphone. They are flying fine...but I want to destroy these bullets after they traveld a certain distance. for example after a bullet "flew" 480px it should be removed.

How can  I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count the distance, when creating a bullet store it's position somewhere. Then every step check:

```
b2Vec2 diff = bullet->GetPosition() - startPosition;
if (diff.Length() > MaxLen)
{
    world->DestroyBody(bullet);
}
```

**EDIT:**

if you want to calculate the path length then store somewhere the previous position and the path length, that is initially 0:

```
b2Vec2 diff = bullet->GetPosition() - prevPosition;
pathLength += diff.Length();
if (pathLength > MaxLen())
{
    //destroy bullet//world->DestroyBody(bullet);
}
```

Comment: that's not excatly what I want..my bullet could travel 400 px. But in a circular motion...than this code wouldn't be valid. Every time the bullet moves...i need to add every pixel(s) (x,y) moved to a float....but I'm not so familiar with maths..any help?

Comment: If the position of the bullet has changed(either by x or/and y) from previous position than +1 pixel has traveled.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple: `world->DestroyBody(body)`. 
And, small advice. For the good practice and performance you should not create bullets over and over again. Reuse it! Just make them invisible and reposition them at a position of a source.

Comment: and how could I track the traveled distance of the body? Because I want to remove it when it has past e.g. 400px.